# Magento Add new condition name (shipping table rate)

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, table-rates

In table rate shipping there are three conditions:

`Weight vs. Destination`
`Price vs. Destination` 
`n°of Items vs. Destination`

It's only possible select it once a time.
Example: if i selected price vs. destination, i can't use weight vs. destination.
I necessity to use Weight vs. Destination and Price vs. Destination together.
Any solution?

Please help me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think it's impossible. You may want to create a new shipping method.

Comment: yes i created a new shipping method with tables, so now i can use Weight vs. Destination and Price vs. Destination together. 
Module for shipping method: Webshopapps Matrix Rates

Comment: can you share with us how to make and use both methods ?